# How to change the location of `web root` folder of EasyPHP?

Tags: location, root, easyphp

Currently on my Windows 7 machine, it is `C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www`

I want to point it into another location on drive D, says `D:\code`

How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @daviddlh 's answer, I have the simple solution for my question.

Open apache configuration file `httpd.conf`

Replace the default value `${path}/www` by the path of our choice, says `D:\code`

Where does it come from? Look for `DocumentRoot` in apache config file (i.e. httpd.conf), we will see the below line which link us to `${path}/www`

```
DocumentRoot "${path}/www"
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to right click on the icon on the Easyphp icon on the taskbar and select configuration->Apache.
This will open httpd.conf in a notepad window.

You need to modify it as follows:

```
DocumentRoot "D:/code"
(...)
# DocumentRootDirectory 
<Directory "D:\code">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
 (...)
 NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot "D:/code/"
   ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4):

Right click the EasyPHP icon, and select Configuration, then Apache. In httpd.conf, do a find for DocumentRoot.  My folder is *C:\php*.  Change these two lines:

1. DocumentRoot "C:\php"
2. <Directory "C:\php">  (the first one just below DocumentRoot...)

Once you have changed *C:\php* to wherever your directory is, right click the EasyPHP icon again and restart.

My apologies, same answer as above.  Did not see it until writing this. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if your apache is using Virtual Hosts, you just have to change the path under the correct "Virtual Host".
In my case, it was:

```
# Virtual Hosts
## Virtualhost localweb
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
#   DocumentRoot "${path}/data/localweb"
    DocumentRoot "D:\Code"
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
#   <Directory "${path}/data/localweb">
    <Directory "D:\Code">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Deny from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```