# Move EasyPHP databases to new directory

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I'm using EasyPHP DevServer VC11 and I've redirected my localweb directory to a folder on my drobox, I now want to move my phpmyadmin files and databases on to my dropbox too.

Why? Because I want to develop from multiple machines but have my files sync across the devices.

I was wandering if someone can tell me what folders I have to move and if I need to change any config files that reference to the location?

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515553/how-to-change-the-location-of-web-root-folder-of-easyphp) guide for the localweb move so I assume I'll have to do some renaming.

I've had a look through httpd.conf and the mysqsql configurtion looking for references to PhpMyAdmin or my databases but I cannot find a reference.

Is it perhaps easier, to install PhpMyAdmin in to my dropbox and then export/import my databases? I will still have to change where it points to though so I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is just a series of PHP scripts, so that part is no problem. Just put the phpMyAdmin folder in your web folder and you'll be fine.

The problem is your MySQL installation. It's definitely not designed to work in this sort of configuration and if you go ahead with it, your likelihood of corrupting your databases is high. The MySQL data directory is going to be dependent on the specific MySQL version it's running from, plus MySQL runs as a daemon so you'll have concurrent access issues.

I *suppose* that if you were **extremely** cautious to only use matching MySQL versions and to ***always*** only run the MySQL daemon on one machine at a time (and wait for the sync to complete before opening another), that you would minimize your chances of destruction, but I do not endorse or suggest trying that.